# Simple image slideshow in p5.js

Tags: setinterval, p5.js

i'm a new coder and i have been trying to create a simple loop or slideshow of 3-5 images on p5.js but i just can't get it right. I've been using the setInterval () function. Please help.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question. Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense.

You need to break your problem down into much smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Can you create a little example program that displays a single image? The [`loadImage()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) function might come in handy here.

**Step 2:** Can you modify the image so it switches from one image to another when you click the mouse?

**Step 3:** Can you increase the number of images? You might use an array for this. Cycle between the images when the user clicks the mouse.

**Step 4:** Finally, can you make it so the images cycle automatically? You might use the [`frameCount`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameCount) variable along with the **modulus** operator to determine when a certain amount of time has gone by.

You need to take these steps one at a time, **try something**, and post a specific question along with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: that nobody gave you a like for your help i dont get. +1 from me